# jQuery form radio input detection on click

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have a form with an interior portion which is laid out basically like this (due to the way it get's styled in the main directory it has to be laid out -poorly- like this):

```
<div id="q38_q42">
    <ul id="q38">
        <li>Q38</li>
        <li>
            <input class="my_input" name="q38" type="radio" value="Yes"/>Yes
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="my_input" name="q38" type="radio" value="No"/>No
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="q39">
        <li>Q39</li>
        <li>
            <input class="my_input" name="q39" type="radio" value="Yes"/>Yes
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="my_input" name="q39" type="radio" value="No"/>No
        </li>
    </ul>
    ...ETC.
</div>
<div id="q43_hidden">
    <p>This is hidden</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to have jQuery detect whenever a user clicks "No" for ANY input inside the `<div id="q38_q42">` and display another div (which is hidden by default) in a different location. Essentially, I need to have the hidden div displayed if ANY of the inputs are "No", even if the next question the user clicks "yes". Right now, if a user clicks "Yes" after a "no" input, it hides the div again. Here's the js:

```
function showDiv(div){$(div).slideDown();}
function hideDiv(div){$(div).slideUp();}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_input').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'No') {
            showDiv('#q43_hidden');
        } else {
            hideDiv('#q43_hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/82Lbhvjw/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the name from **ul**, because both **ul** and **input** have the same name. **ul** does not need a name

```
<ul name="q38" id="q38">

<ul id="q38">
```

Also, your question is a bit confusing. Would you like to add one single div or a div for each one in case of "No"?

So, fix the html and add a class to the elements you want to check...

```
<div id="q38_q42">
    <ul id="q38">
        <li>Q38</li>
        <li>
            Yes
            <input class="my_input" name="q38" type="radio" value="Yes" />
        </li>
        <li>
            No
            <input class="my_input" name="q38" type="radio" value="No" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="q39">
        <li>Q38</li>
        <li>
            Yes
            <input class="my_input" name="q39" type="radio" value="Yes" />
        </li>
        <li>
            No
            <input class="my_input" name="q39" type="radio" value="No" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="error_div" style="background-color:red;display:none;">You clicked No! </div>
```

Now if you want to check if the value of the clicked input is "Yes" or "No", just use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my_input').click(function(){
        alert($(this).val() + " -- " + $(this).attr('name') )
    });
});
```

This will solve your problem in case you need to check if any "No" is checked
and shows the hidden div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my_input').click(function(){
        var has_error = false;
        $('.my_input').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "No" && $(this).prop('checked')){
                has_error = true;
            }
        });
        if(has_error==true){
            $("#error_div").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#error_div").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Working here

https://jsfiddle.net/82Lbhvjw/8/

you can also use $("input:checked") if you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my_input').click(function(){
        var has_error = false;
        $('input:checked').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "No"){
                has_error = true;
            }
        });
        if(has_error==true){
            $("#error_div").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#error_div").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Getting closer! I've updated the question so hopefully the problem is a little more clear. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry. ignore fiddle 7 and move to 8.. I forgot to save it. But I think it solves your problem

Comment: I was able to modify your example to fit what I needed perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I was going to just ask another question, but maybe you can quickly help here too. How would you go about making this a non-specific function activated onclick like this: https://jsfiddle.net/82Lbhvjw/9/

Comment: Well, this won't work with this logic. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I need the function to be flexible so that when the class or acceptable input changes, I don't have to rewrite the entire thing to tailor to the specifics of that portion of the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73679/discussion-between-brunofitas-and-aender).